# Parsing json using volley with images not provided by json

Tags: android, android-volley

**Below is my APi response**

I want to fetch all detail with images of flag that is not given in this api how can I do that please help me I am making college project

```
"matches": [
{
"unique_id": 1144995,
"date": "2018-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
"dateTimeGMT": "2018-12-25T23:30:00.000Z",
"team-1": "Australia",
"team-2": "India",
"type": "Test",
"squad": true,
"toss_winner_team": "India",
"winner_team": "India",
"matchStarted": true
},
{
"unique_id": 1153839,
"date": "2018-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
"dateTimeGMT": "2018-12-25T22:00:00.000Z",
"team-1": "New Zealand",
"team-2": "Sri Lanka",
"type": "Test",
"squad": true,
"toss_winner_team": "Sri Lanka",
"winner_team": "New Zealand",
"matchStarted": true
},
{
"unique_id": 1144153,
"team-2": "Pakistan",
"team-1": "South Africa",
"type": "Test",
"date": "2018-12-26T00:00:00.000Z",
"dateTimeGMT": "2018-12-26T08:00:00.000Z",
"squad": true,
"toss_winner_team": "Pakistan",
"winner_team": "South Africa",
"matchStarted": true
}]
```

Comment: check this tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-fetch-json/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fatch Country Image from name of country than you can use this api and use **flag_base64** key as country flag url.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samayo/country-json/master/src/country-by-flag.json